# nodejs Module.Exports — Can't access object via key

Tags: node.js, module

I have two files, a main and a module file.

```
//module.js 

module.exports.filesystem = "hello!";

//main.js

var filefunctions = require('./module.js');
console.log(filefunctions.filesystem);

//returns "hello!"
```

This works as expected. I'm not sure why the following, doesn't though:

```
//module.js 

var filefunctions = require('./module.js');
console.log(filefunctions[0]);

//main.js 

exports.filesystem = "hello!";
```

I was under the impression that module.exports would create an array, like

```
module.exports = {
filesystem: "hello!";
}
```

Is there something obvious in the syntax that I'm missing? Just trying to wrap my head around these concepts. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your assumption of below code is correct,

```
module.exports = {
filesystem: "hello!";
}
```

the mistake is, you cannot access object attributes as `obj[0]`, can access them as `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]`, try the below code:

```
console.log(filefunctions[Object.keys(filefunctions)[0]]);
```

Comment: Sweet! I wonder why it is so hard to print an object's value in such a situation, when you can usually just print it by identifying the key? Thanks for the help :-)